# How can I add SASS to a generated ASP.NET Core MVC project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sass, dotnet-cli

In particular, I have a project I generated using the command line `dotnet new angular`  and would like to add SASS to it. I already know quite a nice way using `gulp`, one file at a time, but I believe the backbone for client-side management here is WebPack. This is where I run out of pauses between questions.

Plus I see no webpack artefacts in the project, so I could have had a look around and gone with some trial and error, trying to get WebPack to do 'SASS work' for me.